# How to make Firefox allow screen sharing without prompt

Tags: firefox, webrtc, screen-capture, screensharing

I checked the Firefox share screen here https://www.webrtc-experiment.com/Pluginfree-Screen-Sharing/

When I click the button, this dialog show up: https://i.stack.imgur.com/epGHY.png

How can I allow the share screen automatically, Firefox don't even allow remember choice. I know it's security risk, but in my case, I take the risk.
Is there any way ( config, run with hidden flag ) allow website access screen sharing without prompt ?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be turned off via the media.navigator.permission.disabled preference in about:config. Quite useful for automated testing obviously.

Comment: New firefox  show this error message : getDisplayMedia must be called from a user gesture handler , is there anyway to by pass it ?